# Data not show in table

Tags: ajax, laravel

when I submit form I want to show data in table but empty table is visible I don't why this is happen
please help!

Here is my form:

```
<form action="{{ URL::to('/orderTracking') }}" id="otpForm" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:none">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group w-lg-100 w-sm-100  px-3" id="otp" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                    <label><strong>OTP:</strong><span class="text-danger">*</span><span> (OTP sent to your email)</span></label>
                    <input type="hidden" id="pbono-hidden" name="pbono">
                    <input class="form-control" name="OTP" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Order OTP" required/>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btnPink verifyOrder mt-4" id="verifyOrder" value="Verify Order"/>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btnPink TrackOrder mt-4" id="resendOtp" value="Resend OTP"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btnPink TrackOrder" id="checkOtp" style="display:none">Check OTP</button>
        </form>
```

Here is my Ajax:

```
$("#otpForm").submit(function (event) {
                // Prevent the default form submission behavior
                event.preventDefault();

                // Submit the form using AJAX
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr("action"),
                    method: $(this).attr("method"),
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        if (response.Success) {

                        } else {
                            $("#order-error").text(response.error).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                $("#resultTable").show();
                $('#otpForm')[0].reset();
            });
```

Here is my table:

```
<div class="container" id="resultTable" style="display: none">
        <h5 class="text-center text-danger">{{$success['Response'] ?? ''}}</h5>
            <table class="table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Applicant Information</th>
                    <th colspan="2" class="text-center" style="border-left: 2px solid #000000">Vehicle Information</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr class="borderBlack">
                    <td>Dealer Name</td>
                    <td>{{ isset($success['Dealer']) ? $success['Dealer'] : '' }}</td>
                    <td>Variant Booked</td>
                    <td>{{ isset($success['Variant']) ? $success['Variant'] : '' }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="borderBlack">
                    <td>PBO Number</td>
                    <td>{{ isset($success['PBONo']) ? $success['PBONo'] : '' }}</td>
                    <td>Color Exterior</td>
                    <td>{{ isset($success['Exterior']) ? $success['Exterior'] : '' }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="borderBlack">
                    <td>Booking Date</td>
                    <td>{{ isset($success['BookingDate']) ? $success['BookingDate'] : '' }}</td>
                    <td>Color Interior</td>
                    <td>{{ isset($success['Interior']) ? $success['Interior'] : '' }}</td>
                </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

here is my function:

```
public function otp_check(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'OTP'=>'required',
    ]);

    $header = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ];

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client($header);

    if(URL::to('/') == 'https://mgmotors.com.pk'){
        $this->url = 'https://admin.mgmotors.com.pk/';
    }
    $trackingResponse = Http::get('https://api.mgmotors.com.pk/api/orderTracking?pbono='.$request->get('pbono').'&OTP='.$request->get('OTP'));
    $success = json_decode($trackingResponse->getBody(),true);
    return view('order_tracking_system',compact('success'));
}
```

when I submit form I want to show data in table but empty table is visible I don't why this is happen
please help!

Answer (score 0):

there is some problem in your code if you want showing the data after submit form.

this is your return in controller

```
return view('order_tracking_system',compact('success'));
```

if you're using ajax to send request to controller, i think is must be change into return json

```
return response()->json(['data' => $success]);
```

why you should use return response json? because you need to get response after request from ajax and you don't need to reload web browser after submit form. so if you're using return response json in your controller you can get response

```
    $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr("action"),
                method: $(this).attr("method"),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response); // you can get response data from controller
                    // you can do this to show table #resultTable
                   // and do another thing that you want to do
                }
            });
```

to set table data you can do this stuff inside off success function ajax request.

```
           success: function(response) {
                    $('#resultTable').html(`
                    <h5 class="text-center text-danger">${response.data.Response}</h5>
                    <table class="table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Applicant Information</th>
                            <th colspan="2" class="text-center" style="border-left: 2px solid #000000">Vehicle Information</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="borderBlack">
                            <td>Dealer Name</td>
                            <td>${response.data.Dealer}</td>
                            <td>Variant Booked</td>
                            <td>${response.data.Variant}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="borderBlack">
                            <td>PBO Number</td>
                            <td>${response.data.PBONo}</td>
                            <td>Color Exterior</td>
                            <td>${response.data.Exterior}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="borderBlack">
                            <td>Booking Date</td>
                            <td>${response.data.BookingDate}</td>
                            <td>Color Interior</td>
                            <td>${response.data.Interior}</td>
                        </tr>
                    `)
                }
```

for another documentation you can read this [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)